# JSSOR Slider: Is it possible to change navigator options after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I would like to change the number of lanes that the thumbnail navigator shows based on the size of the parent div. So when it's smaller, less lanes are shown.

I was thinking I could use the bind function, like the ScaleSlider function does, but is it possible to update the thumbnail navigator options after the page has loaded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update options after initialization of jssor slider.
Please do something before the initialization then.

Comment: Thanks. I think I might try manipulating the thumbnail divs to see if I can get the functionality that way. I chose JSSOR for this project because the of the touch swipe feature, but it's taken some work to make it look good on smaller mobile devices.

Comment: `jssor_slider1.$Pause();$("slider1_container").remove();` and then repopulte html code and then reinitialize it.